# Using Facebook Pixel code in an index.jade file

Tags: html, angularjs, pixel, jadeify

I'm trying to add the code below to my site. The problem is that Facebook Pixel requires you to use a .html file and this site is using .jade

Wondering how to implement the code. For reference, this is a single page app using angularjs with scripts loading in the index.jade file

```
    <script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '1334448426669891'); // Insert your pixel ID here.
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1334448426669891&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference. What gets served in the end is a html file - jade is just getting compiled to html. So the following code block right after your last body element (or in the head section) will do it

```
script.
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
  n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
  document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', '1334448426669891'); // Insert your pixel ID here.
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
noscript
  img(height='1', width='1', style='display:none', src='https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1334448426669891&ev=PageView&noscript=1')
```

You can also put the js code in a separate file and include that in your index.jade file (assuming the file is called facebookCode.js):

```
script(src='facebookCode.js')
```